# Where are the song files stored on my computer in Geometry Dash?

Tags: geometry-dash

I want to change the default practice mode music, and the menuLoop, with a song I downloaded on GD, but I can't find them. Does anyone happen to know where they are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For Windows:**

The files can be found in `C:\Users\[insert username]\AppData\Local\GeometryDash`

---

**For Mac:**

Go to finder and push <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, type in `~/Library/Caches` and the files will be there.

Answer (score 1):

This question is easy to answer.

**Windows**

This is the directory used for GeometryDash in Windows.

```
C:/Users/YourUserNameGoesHere/AppData/Local/GeometryDash
```

**Mac**

The following directory is used for GeometryDash in Mac.

```
~/library/Cache
```

When you're there, you have to search for a folder that contains audio media. That's all!

Comment: Here's something to keep in mind. You will have to unhide your AppData folders if you can by going to file explorer, click view, and there are 3 checkboxes. Check the last one that says "Hidden Files" and it will now show your files. The reason this happens is because windows by default hides your files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the original songs and other content, right click on the Geometry Dash application and click "Show package contents", then resources. (Mac)

Answer (score 1):

Most Linux distros:

`~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/compatdata/322170/pfx/dosdevices/c:/users/steamuser/Local Settings/Application Data/GeometryDash/`